# Proper setup for high-availability Azure VMs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I would like to achieve a high-availability scenario on two VMs in Azure.
I understand and can follow the directions here:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/manage-vm-availability/

However, my question is this: are the two VMs supposed to be exact replicas of each other, so that when one goes down, the other takes over? Or does the Availability Set look after this, so that the two VMs can have totally different content and still utilise each others' free resources?

Comment: I would have thought they need to be the same. one of the examples in the link you provided is that Microsoft might take one offline to upgrade the host OS. The other server would then need to take the full load. If it's not an exact replica and they take down your primary server, how would the other server know what to do? I should add that this is just my thoughts, not based on anything from Microsoft, and I'm happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with Virtual Machines (currently in Preview), then each VM lives in its own VHD. You can make additional instances by creating a VM from an image you build, but at that point, the new VM lives in its own VHD and the actual disk image will then deviate from any other instance as time goes forward. Of course, if each VM is created from the same image, with the same initialization tasks, etc., then they'd have the same software as well. You'd be responsible for upgrading software versions on all the VMs. If you then put these multiple Virtual Machines in an Availability Set, you'd be assured that the Host OS (underlying OS at machine-level) for the VMs you have would *not* be updated at the same time. You'd also know that different VMs in the Availability Set would be situated in different racks, network segments, etc.

More on Availability Sets: Within an Availability Set, you may have any variety of Virtual Machines - Linux, Windows, different functionality. And... you may define more than one Availability Set.

In the PaaS world, where you set up a Cloud Service with Web and/or Worker roles, those VMs are spawned the exact same way. So adding instances means adding more of the equivalent VMs. If the disk crashed, a new VM would be created just like the others. There are no persistent changes to those OS disks. In the case of Cloud Services, there's fault domains and upgrade domains, which are very similar to availability sets.

Comment: Hi David - so a VM(with a website) would have to be replicated and added to an Availability set to ensure high availaility? OR can the VMs have different content, and if one fails, the other loads the failed image and shares its resources with its current image? Thanks by the way for your comment. (Also to you Greg if you read this)

Comment: There's no loading the failed image. Two VMs = Two VHDs. Set them both  up as web servers (with same setup scripts, etc.). Then run them both, with load-balanced endpoints for 80/443, and in an avail. set. Should one fail (or get taken offline for host os update), the remaining VM takes over the load until failed VM comes back online (remember that it's on a durable disk, triple-replicated). You're responsible for maintaining software versions / Guest OS patches on all instances. In PaaS, you simply change the deployment package, and never worry about Guest OS updates.

Comment: Thanks David - When you say Paas do you mean publishing to Azure cloud instance instead of the VM? Thank you. (Please excuse my lack of knowledge in this area - hence my trying to learn)